# SQL Query to get post_id from wp_posts and and meta_key(s) from wp_postmeta

Tags: database, query, mysql, sql

I have a custom post type called `media_coverage` and need to export via PHPMyAdmin some of the data in that post type that is in `wp_posts` (`post_title`) and also in associated `wp_postmeta` (`meta_key`) keys.

I obviously need to use the post_id, but I don't know how to 1) dynamically pass the `post_id` in the query to get the data from the `wp_posts` table and the post_id associated data from the `wp_postmeta tables`.

And, 2) I don't know how to get multiple `meta_key` values at the same time from `wp_postmeta`.

**This is what I've worked through in PHPMyAdmin:**

• This query shows me all the posts and post_id's, etc, for the `media_coverage` custom post type:

`SELECT* FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'media_coverage'`

• The `post_title` is one bit of data I need to retrieve; this shows me all the post titles of all the `media_coverage` posts from `wp_posts`:

`SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'media_coverage'`

• But what I need to do is also retrieve multiple `meta_key` values from `wp_postmeta`; this gives me one of the `meta_keys` called `coverage_url`:

`SELECT*  FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = '82080' AND meta_key = 'coverage_url'`

**But that's only from post ID 82080, as I don't know how to have the query use all of the post_id's of available `media_coverage` posts.**

**So how do I construct a query like this:**

> SELECT* FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'media_coverage' AND
>
> *(pseudo code)*
>
> the post_title from that post_id in wp_posts
>
> and the meta_key = 'source_name' from that post_id in wp_postmeta
>
> and the meta_key = 'coverage_url'  from that post_id in wp_postmeta

**Edit 9/14/22**

This query works somewhat; I get the columns of `coverage_url` and `source_name`, but I also get all the columns of each post, like draft status, date published, revisions, etc., so limiting the output to `post_id`, `coverage_url` and `source_name` would be nice.

```
SELECT wp_posts.*, 
a.meta_value source_name, 
b.meta_value coverage_url
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta a ON wp_posts.ID = a.post_ID AND a.meta_key='source_name'
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta b ON wp_posts.ID = b.post_ID AND b.meta_key='coverage_url'
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'media_coverage';
```

Comment: This is a question about SQL, not WordPress. But you need to use a `JOIN` statement.

Comment: This is a question about SQL and WordPress. So how do I use a JOIN statement?

Comment: The question is about the SQL language. It's in the context of WordPress in that the circumstantial table names and columns are WordPress-related, but the question itself cannot be answered with knowledge of the WordPress software/APIs, nor is any such knowledge necessary to answer, or beneficial in answering the question. This likely means that the question falls outside [this site's scope](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) - it would likely receive more attention and better answers over on [so] where there is a larger pool of SQL expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

- Query the wp_posts table
- Left join the source_name from wp_posmeta table
- Left join the coverage_url  from wp_posmeta table

Then select the data you want to pull from post, source_name and coverage_url result

Something like this should do

```
SELECT 
    post.ID, 
    post.post_title, 
    sn.meta_value as source_name, 
    cu.meta_value as coverage_url

FROM wp_posts as post

LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as sn
    ON  post.ID = sn.post_id
    AND sn.meta_key = 'source_name'

LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as cu
    ON  post.ID = cu.post_id
    AND cu.meta_key = 'coverage_url'

WHERE post.post_type = 'media_coverage'
```

You Query output should be somethng like

```
---- ID ----+---- post_title ----+---- source_name ----+---- coverage_url
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1        |     Title Here     |   Source Name Here  |  Coverage URL Here
```

Comment: Nice! Works great. The output is "ID | post_title | source_name | coverage_url". The most important appears to be using separate `LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta...` statements for each meta_value.